# Show conditional independance

Tags: conditional-expectation

As part of my excercise i have to show that X and Y are conditionally independent under the condition $(\lfloor X\rfloor,\lfloor Y\rfloor)$
where $X,Y \sim exp(\lambda)$

I previously computed $E[X|\lfloor X\rfloor]$ and I know that I have to show that $f(X,Y|\sim)=f(X|\sim)f(Y|\sim)$ ... but how?

Comment: Conditionally on... what?

Comment: Oh, it was a typo - I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires $X$ and $Y$ to be independently distributed.

$\begin{align}
\because f_{X,Y}(x,y) & = f_X(x)\;f_Y(y)
\\[3ex]
f_X(x\mid \lfloor X\rfloor)
 &= \frac{
f_X(x)
 \operatorname{\bf 1}_{[\lfloor X\rfloor,\lceil X\rceil)}(x)
}{\displaystyle
\int_{\lfloor X\rfloor}^{\lceil X\rceil} f_X(s)\operatorname d s
}
\\[3ex]
\therefore f_{X,Y}(x,y\mid \lfloor X\rfloor, \lfloor Y\rfloor)
 & = \frac{
f_{X,Y}(x,y)
\operatorname{\bf 1}_{[\lfloor X\rfloor, \lceil X\rceil)}(x)
\operatorname{\bf 1}_{[\lfloor Y\rfloor, \lceil Y\rceil)}(y)
}{\displaystyle
\int_{\lfloor X\rfloor}^{\lceil X\rceil}
\int_{\lfloor Y\rfloor}^{\lceil Y\rceil}
 f_{X,Y}(s,t) \operatorname d t\operatorname d s
}
\\[2ex]
 & = \frac{
f_{X}(x)\;f_{Y}(y)
\operatorname{\bf 1}_{[\lfloor X\rfloor, \lceil X\rceil)}(x)
\operatorname{\bf 1}_{[\lfloor Y\rfloor, \lceil Y\rceil)}(y)
}{\displaystyle
\int_{\lfloor X\rfloor}^{\lceil X\rceil}
 f_{X}(s) \operatorname d s
\int_{\lfloor Y\rfloor}^{\lceil Y\rceil}
 f_{Y}(t) \operatorname d t
}
\\[2ex]
 & = f_X(x\mid \lfloor X\rfloor)
 \;f_Y(y\mid \lfloor Y\rfloor)
\\[1ex]
 & = f_X(x\mid \lfloor X\rfloor, \lfloor Y\rfloor)
\;f_Y(y\mid \lfloor X\rfloor, \lfloor Y\rfloor)
 & \text{(Why?)}
\end{align}$